# How to apply Dijkstra Algorithm to Google Maps for finding the shortest path between two points?

Tags: javascript

The below code is giving the three possible routes but I want to get the shortest path(not a straight line), but a path, among the three routes. Using a graph implementation and Dijkstra Algorithm only to get the shortest path.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


var st = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7294, 73.0931);
var en = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0150, 71.5805);

var request = {
    origin: st,
    destination: en,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    // Returns multiple routes
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log(response.routes);
        // Create a new DirectionsRenderer for each route
        for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
            var dr = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            dr.setDirections(response);
            // Tell the DirectionsRenderer which route to display
            dr.setRouteIndex(i);
            dr.setMap(map);

            // Display the distance:
            document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML += "Route " + i + ": " +
              (response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000 + "killo meters, ";
            console.log((response.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000 + "killo meters");
            // Display the duration:
            document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += "Route " + i + ": " +
              response.routes[i].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds, ";
            console.log(response.routes[i].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds");
        }




    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Google are already using Dijkstra's algorithm or a variation of it to find the shortest path(s). Do you want to find the shortest one from those returned, or do you want to re-compute it yourself? I don't think the latter is possible though, as I don't think Google exposes the graph of roads.

Comment: 1. Get all the possible routes between two points from Google Map API along with distances and junctions.
2.Create a graph and map all the routes on the graph.
3.Program the Dijaskera’s Algorithm and run it on graph to get the best shortest path.

Comment: Can you let us know what is the actual problem you're trying to solve? I doubt you'll ever get "all possible routes between two points" from the Google Maps API. You'll get a selection of possible routes, but not all of them. Google already run some form of SPF algorithm on their side, why would you want to do it again? If you want the shortest (in terms of distance), you can use the returned data to find the shortest, you don't need to recompute anything.

Comment: here is the requirement of my project

Comment: 1.Get all the possible routes between two points from Google Map API along with distances and junctions.
2.Create a graph and map all the routes on the graph.
3.Program the Dijaskera’s Algorithm and run it on graph to get the best shortest path.

Comment: That looks like an assignment rather than a project.

Comment: yeah its an assignment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to apply Dijkstra Algorithm you should define your vertices that you want to go through.

Once you have the vertices you can do it by simply applying the algorithm.

Right now I am working on the same thing on this repo:
https://github.com/saba96/droneRoute
it might help you for implementation

Comment: i want the path along the roads for which the travelmode is driving.

Comment: I think that you may need to use another algorithm as you don't have graph and your looking for Continuous space shortest path.